# Changing state from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components:

- A parent component with a list of products
- A child component a few levels deeper with a product

Child component should change the state in parent component with the help of passed callback from parent to child.

However, I get an error: **Rendered more hooks than during the previous render**

Code:

```
// Parent
const ProductsListScreen = () => {
  const [localData, setLocalData] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, count: 1 }
  ]);

  const onProductChecked = ({ id, count }) => {
    const checkedItemIndex = localData.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    const checkedItem = checkedItemIndex ? localData[checkedItemIndex] : null;
    if (checkedItem) {
      // If the input count is equal to item's count in state - set checked to true
      if (checkedItem.count == count) {
        // Set parent state of checked product to checked true
        setLocalTaskItems((prevState) => [
          ...prevState.slice(0, checkedItemIndex),
          {
            ...prevState[checkedItemIndex],
            countIsGood: true,
          },
          ...prevState.slice(idx + 1),
        ]);
      }
    }
  };
  // List of products 
  return <ProductsList onProductChecked={onProductChecked} />;
};
```

---

```
// Child a few levels deeper - Product
const onContinuePress = (params, callback) => {
  // onProductChecked callback
  callback(params);
};
const Product = ({ onProductChecked }) => {
  const id = 1;
  const count = 1;
  return (
    <Button
      onPress={() =>
        onContinuePress(
          {
            id,
            count,
          },
          onProductChecked
        )
      }
    >
      Submit
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: In your child component, you did not receive the `onProductChecked` function.

const Product = ({onProductChecked}) => {........}

Comment: I will try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Send `localData` and `setLocalData` as props to the child and do `onProductChecked` in there with `props.localData` and `props.setLocalData`

like this

```
<ProductsList localData={localData} setLocalData={setLocalData} />;
```

Comment: But I do not want the child Product component to be aware of the other products state